# To access Github private ropositories in rhomobile

Tags: json, rhomobile, github-api

I am trying to access and list GitHub private repositories for logged in user via Github API.While i managed to list public,forked and watched repositories ,i dont know how to use access token getting private repositories list.
  I am trying improve my Github client using Rhomobile.

Answer (score 1):

Making a GET request to `https://api.github.com/user/repos` will get you both the public and private repositories for the currently authenticated user.

The documentation is available [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/).

Comment: Kevin, As of today, the API only returns 'public' repositories for a user. Private repositories can only be fetched for orgs.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. There are two ways of getting a user's repos. One heading says: "your repos" and another "a user's repo". I was wrongly using the second. Thanks Kevin. Your solution worked for me.